# Subscribing Tags in Google Cloud messaging

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, azure-mobile-services

I'm working with Windows Azure Notification Hub and Android, testing the notifications push service through GCM. I'm using tags, pushing notifications from a Web application (back-end) integrated with Windows Azure.

The issue is: I don't know how to subscribe from an Android App to listen to those tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Custom API with Azure Mobile Apps Server SDK.  This should take the device registration Id and then do the registration with Notification Hubs.  Azure Mobile Apps Server SDK wraps the Notification Hubs SDK for this purpose.

In your client, you can follow the appropriate Client SDK tutorial on push (Android is [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-push/)), but use [InvokeApi](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/MobileServiceClient.html#invokeApi-java.lang.String-com.google.gson.JsonElement-java.lang.String-java.util.List-) to invoke your custom API to do the registration instead of calling [client.getPush().register()](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/notifications/MobileServicePush.html#register-java.lang.String-com.google.gson.JsonObject-).

Another good reference is the [Android Client HOWTO Docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library/).